# How do I stop when my first IF is met and not have the two welcome alerts after the first IF is met

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```js
var guestlist = ["Angela", "Jack", "Thu", "Amy", "TC"];

var name = prompt("What is your name?");

if (name === "TC") {
  alert("Welcome " + name + " to the party!");
  return;
} else {
  var firstChar = name.slice(0, 1);
  var upperCaseChar = firstChar.toUpperCase();
  var lastChar = name.slice(1, name.length);
  var lowerCaseChar = lastChar.toLowerCase();
  var completeChar = upperCaseChar + lowerCaseChar;
  var name = completeChar;
}

if (guestlist.includes(name)) {
  alert("Welcome " + name + " to the party!");
} else {
  alert("Sorry, " + name + ". Unfortunately, you are not on the list.")
}
```

I just started javascript. So, I am trying to see how I can get the first IF to stop. Thank you, guys!

Comment: `return` has to be inside a function. Where's the function?

Comment: If this code is inside a function, it should do what you want. The `return` statement will return from the function, so the second `if` will be skipped.

Comment: use `return '';`  returning nothing does actually gets skipped by some browsers for some reason

Comment: @YasserCHENIK I find that very difficult to believe. It would break millions of JS functions. Please provide some proof of that claim.

Comment: @Barmar
i remember from an old series of tests we did back at 2018 , i think in `opera` `return ;` gets ignored

Comment: @YasserCHENIK I still find it hard to believe that such a fatal design error could exist in a JS implementation that received any significant use. It would never make it past even the most basic testing, and few web sites would work in that browser.

Comment: There are some situations involving ASI where something that looks like an empty `return` is actually something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this.

```
const guestlist = ["Angela", "Jack", "Thu", "Amy", "TC"];

const name = prompt("What is your name?");

const firstChar = name.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase();
const lastChar = name.slice(1, name.length).toLowerCase();
const completeChar = firstChar + lastChar;

if (name === "TC") {
  alert("Welcome " + name + " to the party!");
} else if(guestlist.includes(completeChar)){
  alert("Welcome " + completeChar + " to the party!");
}else{
  alert("Sorry, " + completeChar + ". Unfortunately, you are not on the list.")
}
```

Now lets go over it bit by bit on why and how it's been changed:

1. Change all of your **vars** to **consts** according to the new ECMA coding standards.
2. You can stack methods and instead of having:

   `var firstChar = name.slice(0, 1);`
   `var upperCaseChar = firstChar.toUpperCase();`

You can simply do it in a single line like this: `const firstChar = name.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase();`

3. Go check out [THE MDN WEBDOCS for If...else statements and control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), in order to gain better understanding how to write `if...else` statements that have several conditions inside.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your other if statements inside your first if's else statement and at the end of 'if' you don't need to use return, its useless (unless there is more code to it and your code is inside some function that must break at the point of return to stop execution)

```
var guestlist = ["Angela", "Jack", "Thu", "Amy", "TC"];
    
    var name = prompt("What is your name?");
    
    if (name === "TC") {
      alert("Welcome " + name + " to the party!");
      //return; no need for this
    } 
    else {
      var firstChar = name.slice(0,1);
    var upperCaseChar = firstChar.toUpperCase();
    var lastChar = name.slice(1,name.length);
    var lowerCaseChar = lastChar.toLowerCase();
    var completeChar = upperCaseChar + lowerCaseChar;
    var name = completeChar;
    
    if (guestlist.includes(name)) {
      alert("Welcome " + name + " to the party!");
    } 
    else {
        alert("Sorry, " + name + ". Unfortunately, you are not on the list.")
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please indent your code so the structure is more apparent. If you use the Snippet editor, you can use the Tidy button to clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stop function to stop in the first IF!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

</html>
<script>
  var guestlist = ["Angela", "Jack", "Thu", "Amy", "TC"];

  var name = prompt("What is your name?");

  if (name === "TC") {
    alert("Welcome " + name + " to the party!");
    stop();
  } else {
    var firstChar = name.slice(0, 1);
    var upperCaseChar = firstChar.toUpperCase();
    var lastChar = name.slice(1, name.length);
    var lowerCaseChar = lastChar.toLowerCase();
    var completeChar = upperCaseChar + lowerCaseChar;
    var name = completeChar;
  }

  if (guestlist.includes(name)) {
    alert("Welcome " + name + " to the party!");
  } else {
    alert("Sorry, " + name + ". Unfortunately, you are not on the list.");
  }
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `stop` is a function, you have to call it as `stop()`.

Comment: Barmar, I have coded the page, but the `stop` function worked for me..

Comment: I clicked "Run code snippet". When I entered `TC` I got two alerts.

Comment: Yeah but, one is the `prompt()` and the other is the `alert()` in which we get notified that name is one of the`guestlist` or not one of them!

Comment: Brother Barmar, but I only got 1 alert when I typed in `Jack`

Comment: Of course. The double alert only happens with TC, since that's the entry that matches both conditions.

Comment: Yes Barmar, you're correct! The `TC` is matching both the conditions, but this wasn't the question asked I guess? It was only asking about how to stop the function in the first `IF`

Comment: And the first `if` only succeeds when you type `TC`. But you're not stopping then.

Comment: Then I guess we need to add `stop` function in the else statement? Right?

Comment: No, because there's no alert in the `else` block. Actually, that doesn't even need to be in `else` if we stop in the `if`, it can just be top-level code.

Comment: If you just change `stop;` to `stop();` I think it will do what you intend.

Comment: Yes I guess, I'll give it a try by changing it from `stop` to `stop()`

Comment: Had I nice discussion with you about this. 

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).